# How do I make my scala/akka/spray webservice respond with xml or json, depending on the ACCEPT headers

Tags: xml, json, akka, spray, spray-json

I've written the ugliest Marshaller for my json data on earth.  It works, despite its hideousness.  The problem is that the moment I add code to marshal the xml, it ONLY marshals xml and quits accepting json.  Can someone give me an example of a better way to do this?  I just want to be able to marshal and unmarshal my objects to both xml and json depending on what ACCEPT header is provided.

```
trait StupidFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport with MetaMarshallers {
  val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ").withLocale(
    Locale.ROOT).withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC)
  val periodFormatter: PeriodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(1)
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days").appendSeparator(", ").printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendHours()
    .appendSeparator(":").printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":").appendSeconds()
    .toFormatter

  /*implicit val dataResultXmlMarshaller: Marshaller[DataResult] =
    Marshaller.delegate[DataResult, NodeSeq](`text/xml`, `application/xml`, `text/html`, `application/xhtml+xml`)
    { d: DataResult =>
      <DataResult>
        <ApplicationVersion>{d.applicationVersion}</ApplicationVersion>
        <Datestamp>{d.dateStamp}</Datestamp>
        <IsHealthy>{d.isHealthy}</IsHealthy>
        <MemFree>{d.memFree}</MemFree>
        <MemMax>{d.memMax}</MemMax>
        <MemPeak>{d.memPeak}</MemPeak>
        <MemUsed>{d.memUsed}</MemUsed>
        <ServiceHostIp>{d.serviceHostIp}</ServiceHostIp>
        <Uptime>{periodFormatter.print(d.uptime)}</Uptime>
        <OptionalElements></OptionalElements>
      </DataResult>
    }*/

  implicit object DataResultJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[DataResult] {
    def write(d: DataResult) = {
      JsObject(
        "ApplicationVersion" -> JsString(d.applicationVersion),
        "Datestamp" -> JsNumber(d.dateStamp),
        "IsHealthy" -> JsBoolean(d.isHealthy),
        "MemFree" -> JsNumber(d.memFree),
        "MemMax" -> JsNumber(d.memMax),
        "MemPeak" -> JsNumber(d.memPeak),
        "MemUsed" -> JsNumber(d.memUsed),
        "ServiceHostIp" -> JsString(d.serviceHostIp),
        "Uptime" -> JsString(periodFormatter.print(d.uptime)),
        "OptionalElements" -> JsObject (
          "OptionalElement" -> (
            for (oe <- d.optionalElements if d.optionalElements.size > 0) yield {
              JsObject (
                "DataType" -> JsString(oe.dataType),
                "Description" -> JsString(oe.description),
                "LastUpdated" -> JsString(formatter.print(oe.lastUpdated)),
                "Name" -> JsString(oe.name),
                "Value" -> JsString(oe.value)
              )
            }
            ).collect { case v: JsObject => v.fields }.toJson
        )
      )
    }

    def read(js: JsValue) = {
      js.asJsObject.getFields("ApplicationVersion", "DateStamp", "IsHealthy", "MemFree", "MemMax", "MemPeak",
        "MemUsed", "ServiceHostIP", "Uptime", "OptionalElement") match {
        case Seq(
        JsString(applicationVersion),
        JsNumber(dateStamp),
        JsBoolean(isHealthy),
        JsNumber(memFree),
        JsNumber(memMax),
        JsNumber(memPeak),
        JsNumber(memUsed),
        JsString(serviceHostIp),
        JsString(uptime),
        JsArray(optionalElements)
        ) => { DataResult (
          applicationVersion,
          dateStamp.toLong,
          isHealthy,
          memFree.toLong,
          memMax.toLong,
          memPeak.toLong,
          memUsed.toLong,
          serviceHostIp,
          Period.parse(uptime, periodFormatter),
          (for (oe <- optionalElements if optionalElements.size > 0) yield {
            oe.asJsObject.getFields("DataType", "Description", "LastUpdated", "Name", "Value") match {
              case Seq(
              JsString(dataType),
              JsString(description),
              JsString(lastUpdated),
              JsString(name),
              JsString(value)
              ) => OptionalElement (
                dataType,
                description,
                DateTime.parse(lastUpdated, formatter),
                name, value)
            }
          }).toList)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As you observed it's currently harder to do than you would imagine. We have an issue open to improve the situation: https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/581

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing a REST interface the best way would be to simply determine the type based on the extension of your path request, `.json` or `.xml`. This way your API will be easier to consume. The [HTTP/1.1 Accept header documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) shows that the content negotiation is a little complicated.

Answering your question, Spray supports a basic level of content negotiation. The `HttpMessage` class contains a method [`isMediaTypeAccepted`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.2-M8/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpMessage.scala#L155) which also is used by a bunch of other methods in the same class.

Of course `HttpMessage` is re-used on the request and on the response side as well. Hopefully this points you in aright direction.

Comment: I plan on determining the type based on the path request as you suggest; however, I'm also making it so that the user can specify with Accept headers.  I am familiar with the complexities of content negotiation; Spray just has some magic in the marshalers that I don't understand yet.  I can't figure out how to use the isMediaTypeAccepted in my routes, but I'll keep looking.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: 10 minutes after I typed that, I figured out how to dictate the MediaType of the response.  It's so easy it's offensive.  In the route you use the respondWithMediaType function and then specify the MediaType of your response.  `val route = path("soh" / "v1" / "json") {
        get {
          respondWithMediaType(\`application/json\`) {
            complete {
              (scanManager ? Example).mapTo[DataResult]
            }
          }
        }
      }` I got it working, but it's a hack job.  I'll post a full solution in a a little bit and see if people can suggest the best way to do it.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for the record.  This is a gigantic pain in the ass to to with Spray.  Fortunately, I don't need the xml version right now.

Comment: If anyone cares, I bailed on spray and moved over to Scalatra.  This stuff is effortless in Scalatra.  I highly recommend it.  Despite it not being nearly as idiomatic Scala as Spray, it's explicit and it works.  There's very little magic going on, which I really like.

Comment: I found Spray too complicated to use as well. akka-http will be coming through at some point but I suspect Scalatra will stand its ground in terms of simplicity. Gets the job done.